# Time bound tasks using ExectutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have long running tasks submitted to a `ExecutorService`. The task could run for quite some time. Meanwhile, new tasks are submitted to the internal blocking queue.

On completion of the submitted task, a notification is sent back to release tasks from the queue for execution. However, sometimes, the notification is not triggered, either because of programming errors or network issues. In such scenarios, there is a possibility that my task queue will grow quiet large and I might encounter a scenario where the tasks may lie forever in the queue.

To overcome this, I am thinking of writing a thread which will check periodically the time for which the task is lying idle in the queue. If the task is lying in the queue for say 15 minutes, I will assume that the earlier submitted task encountered a error and hence did not return. I will then evict the task from the queue and allow it to get executed.

Is there any existing mechanism to handle this or I will have to write this custom logic?

Note:
The reason I am not preferring `ScheduledExecutor` service is because not all tasks are to be executed periodically. Only failure scenarios should execute after certain delay.

**EDIT**
Brief overview of the architecture
The solution that I am designing should support many concurrent static file downloads. Typically there could be thousands of download requests. The download requests are triggered from a UI based application. That way I know when the requests would be triggered. Taking advantage of this approach , I intend to throttle the download requests.

What happens when a user creates a request for say 300 download requests?

1. Application worker threads create 300 tasks for download
2. 100 tasks are submitted.I have a defined MAX HTTP thread pool size of say 100. This means I can support maximum of 100 synchronous parallel downloads (servlet 2.5) The task in turn asks the remote HTTP clients to perform a HTTP get. Note that HTTP threads are not in play yet
3. Remaining 200 requests are queued.
4. The HTTP client perfomr a HTTP Get. The HTTP threads now streams the response in a BLOCKING fashion.
5. Once I receive a 200 OK, I create a notification to inform that one of the client has completed the download.
6. The throttle will now release/submit one of the task from the previously queued 200 requests.

In scenarios where I am able to receive responses (HTTP 200/ HTTP 500 etc) the throttling mechanism works like a charm. But in case where say for example , the servlet itself threw a exception, I get no response back to indicate a HTTP worker thread is free .So there is a possibility that the task remain in the queue for ever. To overcome this, I was thinking of a timer based approach, where if there  no HTTP response for 15 minutes, submit the next-in queue task for execution. Kind of fall back mechanism to avoid major memory leaks.

Comment: Please show some code. Notifying of finished execution should not be necessary. ExecutorService should pick up next Task automatically. Why do you do this? Providing a bounded queue, you can also write your own "overflow-handler". It has been quite a while since I've done this but if you are interested, I'll go find some example.

Comment: @Fildor It is necessary in my case. The tasks triggers the client for a HTTP GET, which in turn consume worker threads from http thread pool and so on and so forth. The design is convoluted than it might appear and will take quite some explaining to get this crystal clear.. But lets assume I need the notification.

Comment: Then you should wrap all task-code in try catch and do the notification in a finally block. (And of course handle exceptions appropriately.)

Comment: @Fildor Wish it was that simple. Some of the issues are not java Exceptions . For example, say the response is a NACK for not submitting all the parameters required for the task to get executed. I am indeed handling all the exceptions and NACK's that I have encountered till now. But I suspect there are some more scenarios which could cause memory leaks. Just to be sure the tasks gets executed at some point of time.

Comment: Can you please give us some little more overview over your architecture? It is really hard to give sophisticated advice if the architecture is really this complicated.

Comment: @Fildor Update the architecture. Please have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83840/discussion-between-vishal-p-and-fildor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Limit the maximum amount of time allowed for a task by calling `get()` with a timeout and on catching `TimeoutException`, perform your clean up.

Here's an implementation that doesn't block the main thread while waiting:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
ExecutorService monitor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(99);

public void submit(Runnable task) {
    Runnable monitorTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Future<?> future = executor.submit(task);
            try {
                future.get(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // retry waiting. iterative approach not shown here
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // your task exploded
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                // your task timed out - perform clean up, eg
                future.cancel(true);
            }               
        }
    };
    monitor.submit(monitorTask);
}
```

Separate thread pools are used to prevent there being no threads available to monitor, but a thread available to execute the task leading to an unmonitored task.

Comment: I quite liked the solution. But, waiting on the get makes my application single threaded? I have 100 parallel threads and cant wait to afford to wait on return of 1 get , unless I am not interpreting it incorrectly.

Comment: `future.get(timeout, timeUnit)` will not cancel the task if the timeout is exceeded:  The timeout only means that the caller to stop waiting.  You should also call `future.cancel(true)` if the get(...) call throws a `TimeoutException`.

Comment: @james I initially intended this to be just the bare minimum code, but your comment is good advice and has been added to the code.

Comment: @Bohemian That's a brilliant solution. Never imagined one can use the thread pool API this way. My only worry with this approach is the over use of threads for monitoring purpose. 100 extra threads to monitor the future. My in-elegant solution would be to record the time the task is inserted and then periodically (15  minutes) run a single thread to check which tasks have exceeded 15 minutes. If there are ,then evict the older tasks and allow newer tasks to get executed. Does that makes sense or am I very naive with this approach.

Comment: @VishalP while threads do consume resources, waiting ones (like these monitors) get "parked" to the side and shouldn't cause too much problem.